# Chrome Console SameSite Cookie Attribute Warning

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is anybody else getting this Chrome console warning?

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at  was set
>   without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only
>   deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with
>   `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer
>   tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at 
>   and .

In Chrome Flags chrome://flags/ I've tried disabling both:

- SameSite by default cookies
- Cookies without SameSite must be secure

And the warning won't go away.

Comment: I had this because I was running/debugging multiple sites on localhost and the cookies were still there from an old site I was debugging.  After i cleared the application cache and reloaded the page the errors did not return.  So in short, try clearing your cache.

Comment: As @Helzgate mentioned, this was my case as well. And I confirmed by opening an incognito window with dev console open and the warnings disappeared 

Comment: In my case disabling SameSite=None hidden the warning.

Comment: I would be really nice if Chrome mentioned the name of the offending Cookie in the console message.

Comment: https://textslashplain.com/2019/09/30/same-site-cookies-by-default/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can disable them through chrome://flags Cookie Deprecation messages disabled.

[image: Screenshot of chrome://flags with option to disable]

Comment: your website visitors can still see it. I don't think you should disable it. rather fix the problem. if you are a developer/owner for the site.

Comment: _Obviously_ you should fix it but the question was about disabling the warning.

Comment: This shouldn't be the chosen answer. It is not fixing, it is sweeping message under carpet.

Comment: You're not wrong, but again the original question was about disabling the warning. The original accepted answer has been deleted and it did address how to take care of the issue. Feel free to submit an answer that addresses how to fix it, and I'll still leave this up for people who are trying to disable the message for development on localhost, as I was.

Comment: A majority of these warnings are from third parties (in my case, all), so it's not necessarily up to *us* to fix it. We can't tell Google to fix their cookies and expect to get a response. This fix keeps the console clean for developers working on the the code they *can* control, thanks.

Comment: Please anyone who has this problem do not apply this solution to it!

Comment: Why not? I get a lot of this and this is cluttering console. It is harder to look for messages that do come from my site, not others

Comment: @displacedtexan can you please delete this answer so new developers don't get confused and do this--one should not ignore these warnings!

Answer (score 51):

This is something that the third-party cookie setters (like Stripe) need to handle on their end.

I reached out to Stripe because I was getting this message for Stripe payments.

**Stripe support response:**

*It looks like we're already tracking this internally as this warning comes from Stripe.js, not from react-stripe-elements. For now this is a warning and won't affect payments, and we're working on a fix which will eliminate this message and be compatible with Chrome's upcoming cookie-handling changes.*

*(Me) So, it's all on your end? I don't need to do anything?*

*No, this is something we have to get worked out on our end.*

---

Oh, if you're a developer at Stripe/Facebook/Pinterest/so-forth, this answer won't work for you ;)

Comment: Thanks, I had exactly same issue with Stripe and was going to contact them. Now I know, what is the problem.

Comment: Same here. Thanks a lot for taking the time to post this.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome version 80 will be available 4th of February. It looks like the console 'SameSite Cookie Attribute' warning is finally solved by Google. You can download [Chrome Beta](https://google.com/chrome/beta/) and make your own tests before the launch of the official version 80.

Comment: I am using 83..
still facing same issue with that cookies same site disabled option

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with paypal script and since its only them able to set the cookie, they need to fix it so browsers defaulting to this feature will be able to show the content to users properly.

Comment: We apologize for any inconvenience.

We have notified the product development teams about the warning message display on chrome console and the warning message will not affect any PayPal transactions, also our internal teams are aware of the future updates. 

Thank you for helping us.

Sincerely,
Srinivasan
Merchant Technical Support
PayPal, Inc.

ref:_00D30LaY._5002E1RKeGP:ref

Answer (score 1):

This is what was required for me in order to finally fix the problem. Read the warning carefully and enabled/disabled required elements in my google chrome settings

1. in you URL type chrome://flags
2. in the search box (Search flags) type cookie
3. follow the screenshot
   [image]

Do not ignore the warning and hide the warning messages!

Consider this as a workaround, Ideally whichever 3rd party app you are trying to load needs to have `SameSite=None and Secure` params in their headers set.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing my site data worked for me, and i hope it helps others:

[image]

I am using the same vuejs - Axios setup as a previous development enviorment which was utilizing the new PWA tech. So clearing the Application cache was the fix.