# How to fix this "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://facebook.com/" in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension and I put a Facebook like box in it.

All code is the original Facebook code. Didn't change anything.

Recently I've got these errors:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://facebook.com/
was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome 
will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with 
`SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools 
under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

The extension has nothing to do with servers and I did some Google search only found topics about PHP or Java solution, which is quite weird.

How can I fix it in my Chrome extension? Or should I just drop Facebook like-box before they fix anything?

Comment: This is duplicated, please look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211333/chrome-console-samesite-cookie-attribute-warning

Answer (score -1):

VM5:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at [facebook](https://facebook.com/) was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592) and [here](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032).