# Warning in console.log when adding embedded google maps

Tags: javascript, html, angular, cookies, websecurity

I want to add google maps (embedded) map in my web app. I'm building an angular 8 and using built-in server but still in console.log showing warnings

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review coo...
```

What I've done in my code in my ngOnInit method, I already added this

```
    this.cookieService.set('cross-site-cookie',"bar");
    this.cookieService.set('SameSite','SameSite=None; Secure');
```

The code above I use npm package called ngx-cookie-service. Also as I made myself a reference to this website

```
https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/javascript.md
```

I'm not sure either I have done it right or wrong. What I did is I just copy entirely using "copy link" from google maps from my place. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

You can disable them through chrome://flags Cookie Deprecation messages disabled.

[Chrome Console SameSite Cookie Attribute Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211333/chrome-console-samesite-cookie-attribute-warning)

If you can to add a google map full follow this tutorial:

https://dev.to/devpato/setup-google-map-in-angular-app-the-pro-way-3m9p

Easier way to add a google map to your angular app:
https://dev.to/devpato/setup-google-maps-with-agm-in-angular-app-33em

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I think it works for the npm install below. Just, is it free? I just want to call from web. And how to enable view larger map?

Comment: @AmirulIdzham updated the answer. Yes, they are free :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="your google map url"></iframe>
```

Try this out.

Comment: Sorry sir, not working. I got this from google. But same result
    <iframe src="url" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>