# Why am I getting "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"?

Tags: cookies, express-session

In a Chrome warning, it says:

> Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-party use.

How do I do this correctly using `express-session`?

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://elated-jackson-28b73e.netlify.app"] //Swap this with the client url 
  })
);
var sess = {
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: {}
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
  sess.cookie.secure = true // serve secure cookies
  sess.cookie.sameSite = 'none'
}

app.use(session(sess))
```

Comment: What I found is that this is not a client side issue, but on the server side, also if you are using an external api you have no control over this issue. @Squirrl

Comment: This should the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503751/cross-domain-session-cookie-express-api-on-heroku-react-app-on-netlify/66553425#66553425

Comment: The related problem with Fetch https://stackoverflow.com/a/72456007/8552163

Answer (score 36):

you are getting this because you are using a resource from another site and that server is attempting to set a "cookie" but, it does not have the SameSite attribute set, which is being reported in newer versions of browsers.

**this (may) also be shown** if you are trying to access the server page from **local computer (xampp), which generally doesn't has SSL installed;**

set the header line in your server page (if in PHP) as below:
`header("Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=whatever; SameSite=None; Secure");`

**(remember: this must be solved from the server side.)**

Comment: What if I have this error in my react application? Any way to achieve the same?

Comment: @EklavyaChandra it should be gone when it's up in the server.

Comment: In which file am i supposed to add this code?

Comment: @CherrylRarewings this is meant to be set on a server. If you are not in control of the server setting the cookie, there's nothing you can do about this. You should reach out to support.

Answer (score 4):

i got the same issue when run my code in localhost. The affected resource is _ga, _gid, _utma, _utmz. All of them from unpkg.com
and i got marker image leaflet failed request but doesnt affect the page.

since i dont understand what the specific problem so i just delete the affected resource cookies in inspect element and the code will run without notif again.

thought i know if it's better to not answer based by personal experience. just tell me if it's not help at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google login button or any other identity service add this:

```
<GoogleLogin onSuccess={() =>()} onError={() => ()} cookiePolicy='single-host-origin'/>
```

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work please, any other suggestions?

Comment: make sure to the app component wrap it in <googleOauthprovider> from the package @react-oauth/google with your client id mentioned Example: <googleoauthprovider clientId='your_id'> <component/> </googleoauthprovider>