# Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am practicing simple HTML CSS JS and anytime I give my img a source of a wikipedia link, I get the error "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute" in my browser console.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code where you are using an `img` tag and how you are providing the value for `src`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63273838/why-am-i-getting-indicate-whether-to-send-a-cookie-in-a-cross-site-request-by-s)