# NextJs youtube Iframe cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cookies, next.js

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in my next.js web app. Everything works fine from the "functional" point of view, however Chrome highlight the following issue related to cookies (**NOTICE:** I'm already using the `no-cookie` url version, as you will see in the link of the iframe):

```
Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its
SameSite attribute
```

I understand the underlying problem: youtube is trying to set a cookie and since it is a cross-origin request the browser raise an issue. However, I want to understand how to solve the problem using next.

Just to give further information I'm using nginx as webserver and pm2 to run nextjs server-side.

This is the iframe:

```
       <iframe
            className="relative left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 h-60 2xs:h-80 xs:h-96 lg:h-100 w-full sm:w-2/3"
            src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/s563j8bP6eE"
            title="YouTube video player"
            frameBorder={"0"}
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
            allowFullScreen />
```

**CLARIFICATIONS:**
The purpose of this question is **NOT** to ask **how can I disable** cookies warnings (which is explained in a different answer like this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211333/chrome-console-samesite-cookie-attribute-warning)), but instead I want to ask if there was a way to configure Youtube FramerAPI to avoid the issue.

---

**Update:**

I've managed to deploy my application on a server (with HTTPS) and it doesn't raise any issue. The issue might be **related to local development** without HTTPS.

Comment: That's not a problem you can solve from your end at all, YouTube would have to add the SameSite attribute on their end when they are setting that cookie.

Comment: Well, that's sure, but can I (for instance) prevent youtube from setting cookies in any way?

Comment: Only if YT offered any additional parameters for that (which to my knowledge, they don't - using the nocookie domain is already the maximum you can get in that regard, the remaining cookies are considered technically necessary.) But _why_ even? Just because Chrome indicates this as a _potential_ issue, doesn't necessarily mean it absolutely needs fixing.

Comment: It actually blocks the video on the server. I'm reading documentation, maybe I find something that I missed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414166/11613622

Comment: I don't want to modify the security of my browser. The video should be made available to every user

Comment: @AndreaCostanzo1 That's not the answer I linked to said. It said that this needs to be done on YT's side.

Comment: @brc-dd Sorry, It loaded the wrong answer